# Is Converse True, i.e Quotient space of any space is locally connected then space is locally connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, quotient-spaces

$X$ is a locally connected space, and $f: X \to Y$ is onto where $Y$ has the quotient topology then $Y$ is locally connected. ([$X$ is locally connected and $f: X \to Y$ is onto where $Y$ has the quotient topology. Prove that $Y$ is locally connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368956/x-is-locally-connected-and-f-x-to-y-is-onto-where-y-has-the-quotient-top)).

Note-: if quotient map is open map then the converse follows.

Is the converse of the above statement true in general?

I'm thankful for the help.

Comment: The converse is: if $Y$ is locally connected and $q: X \to Y$ is quotient then $X$ is locally connected? This is obviously false...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Well, there is also the possibility of interpreting it as "all quotients are locally connected", in which case it is obviously true.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Not all quotients are locally connected. What do you mean exactly? What true statement do you envision as the converse?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If all quotients are locally connected, then the space itself is locally connected.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That's true but uninteresting, as the identity map is also a quotient map...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Right. But that leaves us with two potential candidates for a converse, neither of which are very interesting (being either trivially true or trivially false).

Comment: Maybe a converse could be: if $f: X \to Y$ is onto continuous and $X$ is locally connected and so is $Y$, then $f$ is quotient? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I didn't, how its false obviously ..plz clarify.

Comment: @Sdd what is the converse statement that you’re interested in? Please state it like a theorem.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma see it came by this
As if, $X$ is locally connected space and **~** be any equivalence relation on$X$, then we can define $Y$=$X$/~ be quotient space, and this will also be a locally connected space. Now MY DOUBT IS  "If $Y$ is locally connected then $X$ is locally connected ? "

and i'm thinking quotient map as, _f :X --> Y, f (x) = [x]_ which induces quotient topology over Y.

Comment: Let $X$ be the rational numbers (not locally connected), and $\sim$ be any equivalence relation with finitely many closed classes (or even one: i.e. all points are equivalent), then $X / \sim$ is locally connected (being finite discrete), while $X$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

So you mean (by the comments): If $q: X \to Y$ is a quotient map and $Y$ is locally connected, then so is $X$?

This is false:

$X=\mathbb{Q}$ in the usual topology, let $Y$ be a finite discrete set and write $\mathbb{Q}$ as a finite union of disjoint closed sets (e.g. $[\sqrt{2}, \rightarrow) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, $(\leftarrow, \sqrt{2}]\cap \mathbb{Q}$, for a two point $Y$, and variations thereof for other numbers. If we're lazy we can just take one set $X$ itself, and $Y$ a singleton) and map each closed set to a different point of $Y$ surjectively. Then the result is a quotient map and $Y$ is locally connected (as all discrete spaces are), and $X$ is not.

Or a simple variation: let $Z$ be any non-locally connected space, let $X$  be a disjoint sum topology of copies of $Z$, and again $Y$ a discrete space (one point for each copy of $Z$) and map each summand to a different point in the discrete space. Etc.